# How do I set the hidden attribute for a directory?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How can I set a newly created directory to be hidden using WiX?

I was hoping for something like:

```
<Directory Id="SomeDir" Name="SomeDir" Hidden="Yes"/>
```

Comment: I see one accepted answer, but one of the links are dead. Did you solve this?

Comment: I don't recall whether I actually used it, but the answer was basically that it must be done through a custom action, which would involve creating a dll with a function to perform the operation, and that would use either the [managed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes) or [native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesa) Windows API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Windows Installer directly, but it can be done through a [custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm). You can find sample VBScript code here:
http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/filesfolders/folders/#ChangeFolderAttribs.htm

You can write a DLL or EXE if you don't want VBScript.